# Shemini Atzeret coincides with Shabbat, Sukkah farewell and last meal

Tags: shabbat, chutz-laaretz, meal-seudah, shmini-atzeres

This year Shemini Azeret and Shabbat coincide.

What is the last meal done in the Sukkah? Is Seudah Shelishit in this context has to take place in the Sukkah?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Isn't your last meal in the sukkah whatever your last meal happens to be? You can eat 15 meals tomorrow if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shulchan Oruch 668 (1) says:

> Outside of Israel, they eat in the sukkah at night and during the day *(of Shemini Atzeres)*
> because it might be the seventh day. They do not bless on this
> sitting.

On the words “ at night and during the day” the Mishna Berurah says:

> (ה) בלילה וביום - אבל לאחר שאכלו סעודתן ביום מנהג העולם שנפטרין מן
> הסוכה ויושבין בבתיהם [מ"א] אבל אי איתרמי ליה לאכול אפילו בין השמשות
> צריך לאכול בסוכה
>
> But after they ate their daytime meal, the custom is that they leave
> the sukkah and dwell in the house. But if they need to eat, even at
> twilight, they have to eat in the sukkah.

Seudah Shelishit is a need to eat after the daytime meal and therefore should be eaten in the sukkah.

Comment: A number of years ago, I was in Golders Green United Synagogue when Dayan M Swift was the minister. Our family did not know here to eat Seudah Shelishis on Shmini Atzeres that fell on Shabbos. I went to ask  Dayan Swift with my finger in the quoted Mishna Berurah.  Dayan Swift had been in Radin during the life of the Chofetz Chaim (see [here](http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/04/guest-post-chief-rabbinate-and.html)). The Dayan said  Seudah Shelishis is to be eaten in the house. I asked that the Mishna Berurah says in the sukkah. He replied that in Radin they ate in the house.

Comment: was he testifying about the minhag haolam in radin or the chafetz chayim's personal practice?

Comment: minhag haolam in radin.